# Qt MySQL use TLS 1.2

Tags: qt, qt5, tls1.2, mysql-connector

I am using Qt 5.9 to connect to a MySQL 5.7 instance.

I am using the server's auto-generated certificates, and I am explicitly setting the ***SSL_KEY***, ***SSL_CERT*** and ***SSL_CA*** options (explicit setup required for the reasons indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58464861/qt-mysql-connect-to-azure-via-ssl)). I set `require_secure_transport=ON` on my database instance configuration, and **I manage to connect to it via TLSv1** (as observed via local packet capture, and it fails if I do not set the SSL_CERT and SSL_KEY options at least).

However, **my client fails to connect if I force my DB instance to only support TLSv1.2, or even down to TLSv1.1**, the error  beinga rather opaque `SSL connection error: unknown error number QMYSQL: Unable to connect` on the application log, and merely a `2 [Note] Bad handshake` message on the server's error log.

I can connect via command line just fine by specifying the same client cert and key files, and specifying TLSv1.2 or any other supported protocol, the command is a plain `mysql -u someuser --password=somepass --host=localhost --ssl-mode=REQUIRED --tls-version=TLSv1.2 --ssl-cert=path/to/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=path/to/client-key.pem`

The [QSqlDatabase api](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#setConnectOptions) has a few options for the MySQL driver, but they do not cover e.g. explicit TLS version settings. Such settings exist for [QSslConfiguration](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslconfiguration.html#protocol), to be used with [QSslSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html).

**Question(s):**

What is the proper way to connect to a MySQL instance via TLSv1.2 in Qt? Are there other configuration options I am missing on the QSqlDatabase class, to enable my client to do so?

Comment: Looks like [OPT_TLS_VERSION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html) is missing from the supported options for QSqlDatabase.
When you compile Qt by yourself you can try to add it and see if this was the only missing option.

Comment: Maybe it's MYSQL_OPT_TLS_CIPHERSUITES and not OPT_TLS_VERSION

Comment: It turns out that the problem was not in the Qt library, but **in the mysqllib version in use**.
During some preliminary tests with recompiling the driver with the latest (as of 2021-06) MySQL [5.7.34](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html) version (and configuring my server to require secure connections), my Qt application started connecting with the highest protocol version supported by the current DB settings.
The OPT_TLS_VERSION support would still be needed to _force_ a minimum protocol version and refuse to connect in case the target DB did not support it.